# SciChart: Working with JavaScript Heatmap Chart

Tags: javascript, scichart, scichart.js

I am using SciChart Library for showing JS Heatmap Chart.

According to the below documentation, the **zValues** variable is generated using *iterate* function but when I try to use it in my HTML & CSS based website, Its not working.

https://demo.scichart.com/javascript-heatmap-chart

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

I have written the following Code:

**Code:**

```
var {sciChartSurface, wasmContext} = await SciChart.SciChartSurface.create("line_chart_3");
// Add XAxis and YAxis
sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(new SciChart.NumericAxis(wasmContext));
sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(new SciChart.NumericAxis(wasmContext));
// Create a Heatmap Data-series. Pass heatValues as a number[][] to the UniformHeatmapDataSeries
var initialZValues: number[][] = iterate(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 200, 0, MAX_SERIES);
var heatmapDataSeries = new SciChart.UniformHeatmapDataSeries(wasmContext,
{
    xStart: 100,
    xStep: 1,
    yStart: 100,
    yStep: 1,
    zValues: initialZValues
});
// Create a Heatmap RenderableSeries with the color map. ColorMap.minimum/maximum defines the values in
// HeatmapDataSeries which correspond to gradient stops at 0..1
var heatmapSeries = new SciChart.UniformHeatmapRenderableSeries(wasmContext,
{
    dataSeries: heatmapDataSeries,
    colorMap: new SciChart.HeatmapColorMap(
    {
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 200,
        gradientStops:
        [
            { offset: 0, color: "#00008B" },
            { offset: 0.2, color: "#6495ED" },
            { offset: 0.4, color: "#006400" },
            { offset: 0.6, color: "#7FFF00" },
            { offset: 0.8, color: "#FFFF00" },
            { offset: 1.0, color: "#FF0000" }
        ]
    })
});
```

The above code is arising error on: var initialZValues: number[][] = iterate(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 200, 0, MAX_SERIES);

Please help.

Comment: @dr-andrew-burnett-thompson Please help.

Comment: I listen to scichart tag so no need to @me. Will take a look!

Comment: btw I logged a bug for this https://abtsoftware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/SCJS-1120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code is Typescript

```
 var initialZValues: number[][] = iterate(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 200, 0, MAX_SERIES);
```

remove the `: number[][]` and it should run.

Comment: But the iterate function is also a typescript one, so we need to convert it also. Don't you have a standalone JS script ? In the website typescript code is added as JS documentation. We can't use them in a pure html css js based wesbite.

Comment: as I said, I logged a bug for this https://abtsoftware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/SCJS-1120. Perhaps worth asking another question how to convert a function from Typescript to Javascript

Comment: If the answer helps you please accept & upvote

Comment: Yes sure. But please try to add a separate tab for JS too.